# Angular checkbox sort

Tags: angularjs, sorting, checkbox

Been looking around for my unique case involving sorting by selected checkboxes, but so far I have come up empty. I currently have a working example (see https://plnkr.co/edit/MtlkshHSoVMw7R1knOzt?p=preview) but unfortunately the requirements are such that two-way binding is not acceptable. Instead, the requirements are that I must select the header and then initiate the sort by selected checkboxes.

Here is the controller.

```
var myApp = angular
    .module("myModule", [])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope) {

    var employees = [
        { id: "1", firstName: "Ed", dateOfBirth: new Date("April, 20, 1973"), gender: "Male", salary: 60000, checked: false },
        { id: "2", firstName: "Martha", dateOfBirth: new Date("April, 20, 1975"), gender: "Female", salary: 70000, checked: false },
        { id: "3", firstName: "Thuy", dateOfBirth: new Date("April, 20, 1977"), gender: "Female", salary: 50000, checked: false },
        { id: "4", firstName: "Frank", dateOfBirth: new Date("April, 20, 1979"), gender: "Male", salary: 90000, checked: false },
        { id: "5", firstName: "Zhenya", dateOfBirth: new Date("April, 20, 1981"), gender: "Female", salary: 100000, checked: false },
    ];   

    $scope.employees = employees;       
    $scope.reverseSort = false;
    $scope.sortColumn = "firstName";


    $scope.sortData = function (column) {

        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
        $scope.sortColumn = column;

    }  
});
```

And here is the HTML

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
          <div ng-controller="myController">
              <table>
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('employee.checked')" ng-model="selectedCheckBox">CheckBoxTest</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('firstName')">Name</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('dateOfBirth')">Date of Birth</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('gender')">Gender</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('salary')">Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees |  orderBy: ['-checked', 'sortColumn']: reverseSort">
                          <td><input type="checkbox" id="employee.firstName" ng-checked="false" ng-model="employee.checked" /></td>
                          <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
                          <td>{{ employee.dateOfBirth | date: "dd/MM/yyyy" }}</td>
                          <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                          <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>        
              </table>
          </div>
      </body>
```

As you can see each columns are being sorted; however, the checkbox is being sorted dynamically, which is undesired behavior. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what do you want exactly?

Comment: I need it to sort only when I click the header and not when I click on the checkbox. So as follows: 1. click on the desired checkbox and 2. go to header and then sort. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Solved your problem.
The issue is that you are using ng-model in your checkbox and it's value is set equlal to employee.checked which is the data you pass when clicking the name header. So I just removed it and works as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://code.angularjs.org/latest/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    table{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
    }

    th {
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

</style>
  </head>
      <body ng-app="myModule">
          <div ng-controller="myController">
              <table>
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('employee.checked')" ng-model="selectedCheckBox">CheckBoxTest</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('firstName')">Name</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('dateOfBirth')">Date of Birth</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('gender')">Gender</th>
                          <th ng-click="sortData('salary')">Salary</th>
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees |  orderBy: ['-checked', 'sortColumn']: reverseSort">
                          <td><input type="checkbox" id="employee.firstName" ng-checked="false" /></td>
                          <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
                          <td>{{ employee.dateOfBirth | date: "dd/MM/yyyy" }}</td>
                          <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                          <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
                      </tr>
                  </tbody>        
              </table>
          </div>
      </body>
</html>
```

Use this as your html.

Comment: Yes, I tried this too, but I what I found was that this doesn't work for different scenarios of clicked checked boxes - they just don't get sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the "checked" property to the employee model and sort using that:

```
  <body ng-app="myModule">
      <div ng-controller="myController">
          <table>
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th ng-click="sortData('checked')">CheckBoxTest</th>
                      <th ng-click="sortData('firstName')">Name</th>
                      <th ng-click="sortData('dateOfBirth')">Date of Birth</th>
                      <th ng-click="sortData('gender')">Gender</th>
                      <th ng-click="sortData('salary')">Salary</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees |  orderBy:sortColumn: reverseSort">
                      <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="employee.checked"  ng-click="sortColumn = 'freeze'" /></td>
                      <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
                      <td>{{ employee.dateOfBirth | date: "dd/MM/yyyy" }}</td>
                      <td>{{ employee.gender }}</td>
                      <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>        
          </table>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Yes, I believe I tried that too, but when you uncheck and recheck the checkboxes, the checkboxes return to sorting dynamically. I believe some code on the .js file is needed.

Comment: See modified answer

Comment: This is close but you'll see that on repeated checking and uncheck and clicking of the header that the checkboxes return to sorting dynamically. I am uncertain whether this will with angular at this point.

Comment: Got it. Check the new answer

Comment: Froze the plunker using your code but you'll see that it reverts to sorting dynamically. Odd that it works when you initially load the page but not afterwards.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/uVp7HFU5WE4gKvhfdMbI?p=preview  - this works except for the first sort... hopefully you can figure that part out

Comment: I finally figured out how to do this and it is by injecting the orderBy into the controller. Here is the link to my final Plunker version https://plnkr.co/edit/MtlkshHSoVMw7R1knOzt?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by injecting the orderBy filter into the controller. I have updated the plunker code to demonstrate how to do this. Thanks all for your responses.

https://plnkr.co/edit/MtlkshHSoVMw7R1knOzt?p=preview

```
angular.module('orderByExample3', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', 'orderByFilter', function($scope, orderBy)
```